# subtract two datetime fields return wrong total of hours value

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datetime

I try to write code that subtract two datetime fields and return the result to TimeSpan object and return the Total Hours value.

```
DateTime x = new DateTime(2013, 7, 18, 12, 57, 40);
DateTime y = new DateTime(2013, 7, 18, 13, 2, 19);
double m = y.Subtract(x).TotalHours;
```

I expect the value of `m` is 0.073166667 but the actual result is 0.0775 why?

**Edit**

I'm sorry I use the google calculator in wrong way BTW thank you @Liran Elisha and @FSou1

Comment: How do you expect m to be 0.073166667? , As 279/3600 gives 0.0775 which seems fine

Comment: kindly give your formula to calculate your desired result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you just do

```
double res = (y - x).TotalHours;
```

because c# already knows so subtract to `dateTime` types and return the result as a `timeSpan`

the result is 0.0775 because the difference is 279 seconds. divide by 60 (to minutes) is 4.65 minutes, divide by 60 again for hours is 0.0775 as you get.

Comment: it returns the same value 0.0775

Comment: way do you expect 0.073166667 @AnasJaber?

Answer (score 3):

Don't understand why you expect 0.073 result, but hope it helped:

[image]

**Code:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime x = new DateTime(2013, 7, 18, 12, 57, 40);
        DateTime y = new DateTime(2013, 7, 18, 13, 2, 19);
        double seconds = y.Subtract(x).TotalSeconds;
        double minuits = y.Subtract(x).TotalMinutes;
        double hours = y.Subtract(x).TotalHours;
        Console.WriteLine("seconds: " + seconds + ", minuits: " + ((float)seconds / 60) + ", hours: " + ((float)seconds / 3600));
        Console.WriteLine("seconds: " + seconds + ", minuits: " + minuits + ", hours: " + hours);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code and the result as text instead of an image?